# Handle Multiple ProgressBar in TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, progress-bar, afnetworking

I have to manage multiple progress bars in a `UITableView`. There are multiple download requests, so how can I identify them?

On `didSelect` method I started the request for download. But how can I manage the downloading ProgressView on each cell?
For downloading file, I am using `AFNetworking`.

**My code**

```
NSString *path=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/p.zip",Document_dir];
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [manager GET:[arrurl objectAtIndex:sender.tag]
                                      parameters:nil
                                         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSData *responseData)
                                         {
                                             //[responseData writeToURL:someLocalURL atomically:YES];
                                             [responseData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
                                         }
                                         failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
                                         {
                                             NSLog(@"Downloading error: %@", error);
                                         }];
```

**Help me to solve this.**

Comment: Use cellFromRowAtIndexPath method, which will retrun you particular cell instance. Using that, update your progressbar and then reload the table. But for this you might require to call a method which is on MainThread.

Comment: @Mrunal, Thanks for your reply. But there is multiple download request. so how can I identify them?

Comment: Where are you monitoring the download progress? (I assume that's what you want to display on your progress bars)